# Rats! WebGL hit a snag - how to debug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, canvas, webgl

Calling `canvas.getContext("webgl");` gets Chrome to trigger the "Rats! WebGL hit a snag" message, and doesn't give any information. How can I fix that?

I'm getting no other information other that `canvas.getContext("webgl")` returns `null` I would not even know that Chrome fails with a message that takes 25% of the phone screen if I was not using the device myself because this triggers no error.

This is part of a function that is supposed to test if WebGL is supported by creating a new canvas and getting a webGL context:

```
var webGLIsSupported = function() {
  if (typeof window.webGLIsSupported !== 'undefined') {return window.webGLIsSupported;}

  var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>')[0];
  var ctx;
  try {
    ctx = canvas.getContext('webgl'); // <- this triggers the message, and fails
  }
  catch (e) {
    window.webGLIsSupported = false;
    return false;
  }
  window.webGLIsSupported = !!ctx;
  return window.webGLIsSupported;
};
```

Where can I start to get info on what's not working? It's quite frustrating to have no logs whatsoever.

Changing `canvas.getContext('webgl')` to `canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl')` makes no difference.

I'm running Chrome 49.0.2623.105 on a Samsung S6.

Comment: you can try going to `about:gpu` after you get the message. There might be log message in there. Be sure to check before you get the message as well to separate any messages from before from messages after. Also post them here if you don't mind. Would love to see what they are

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, checking for `null` is a way to know if the context creation succeeded. But there is no information on the "why" when you only check for it.

There is actually an event which should fire for this exact purpose : [webglcontextcreationerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/webglcontextcreationerror)

It does contain a `statusMessage` property which should give you more info on the "why" it failed to create the context.

From MDN :

```
canvas.addEventListener("webglcontextcreationerror", function(e) {
  console.log(e.statusMessage || "Unknown error"); 
}, false);
```

However, I don't know if you can do anything about the message you got...

Comment: If you try this I'd be curious what messages you get

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. The message is gone as soon I hit the reload option offered by the chrome message (no when I reloaded the page) I'll add that in my code and hope I'll come across the bug again before many of my users do, and will let you know!